# What are the considerations for CPU affinity?

Tags: multithreading, openmp

When should a user set `OMP_PROC_BIND` to `TRUE` in an OMP-parallelized application? It would seem that keeping the thread on the same CPU should be faster because you may be reducing some scheduling and maybe cache movement overhead.

I am interested in the answer to this question in the context of multiple OMP-parallelized processes.

Let's take a concrete example. I have a 48-core box and two similar applications with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=16`. Am I better off letting `OMP_PROC_BIND` be unset and let natural affinity take its course?

Experimenting with `OMP_PROC_BIND=TRUE`, my `libgomp` system seems not to play nicely when there are multiple OMP processes: all 32 threads are scheduled on the same 16 cpus. Without `OMP_PROC_BIND` all 48 cores appear to be used at some point and everything runs faster.

Then the question stands: to what end is CPU affinity?

Answer (score 1):

The most important rule about any performance-related setting is: **measure**, don't guess.

Generally, it is most efficient to pin/bind/set the affinity of each OpenMP threads to one dedicated core (or hardware thread). Pinning threads without ensuring that the core is dedicated for that thread leads to the issues you describe. The two OpenMP processes are separate and they use the same cores because they simply don't know better which cores to chose.

If you have control over all processes on the system you can dispatch them on different sets of cores. There are several things that do the same thing:

1. Use the OS restrict the cpuset for the process and then let OpenMP do the pinning of threads:

   ```
   $ OMP_PROC_BIND=true taskset -c 0-15 ./a
   $ OMP_PROC_BIND=true taskset -c 16-31 ./b
   ```

   Something like that is usually done transparently by HPC batch systems.
2. Use the `libgomp` specific environment variable

   ```
   $ OMP_NUM_THREADS=16 GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-15" ./a
   $ OMP_NUM_THREADS=16 GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="16-32" ./b
   ```
3. Use the powerful but complicated standard `OMP_PLACES` environment variable:

   ```
   $ OMP_NUM_THREADS=16 OMP_PLACES="{0}:16" ./a
   $ OMP_NUM_THREADS=16 OMP_PLACES="{16}:16" ./b
   ```

Now there is another aspect to affinity that is particularly relevant when you have more cores than threads. Depending on the application characteristics it can be beneficial to either place the threads as `close` as possible (faster communication between threads) or `spread` them out over the hardware (more shared resources available). It can be controlled with any of the three related `(G)OMP` environment variables. It all depends on your application and your system - there is no general rule here.

Answer (score 0):

`OMP_PROC_BIND` only prohibits move of a thread between different cpus, it's not a general concept of *affinity*.

For me, *affinity* is to restrict threads to a group of hardware processors. It will be very important if your machine has NUMA architecture, on which moving a thread from a particular group of cpus to another group is inacceptable.

Cited from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fPLACES.html:

> If OMP_PLACES and GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY are unset and OMP_PROC_BIND is either unset or false, threads may be moved between CPUs following no placement policy.

which means if you don't specify affinity policy, one thread might be moved to a different NUMA node. So normally I will use `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` to specify a list of cpus in a single NUMA node to prevent undesired behavior.

Comment: `OMP_PROC_BIND` does in fact support different thread affinity policies (`master`, `close`, `spread`).